# Very slow Minimum value group by query

Tags: mysql

the following query:

```
select t.code, t.value, t.date
from readings t inner join (
    select code, min(date) as MinDate
    from readings
    where date >= "2018-11-1"
    group by code
) tm on t.code = tm.code and t.date = tm.MinDate
```

is taking +1min to respond.

The subquery:

```
select code, min(date) as MinDate
from readings
where date >= "2018-11-1"
group by code
```

returns in one second. Plus if you take the whole query and replace min() with max() it also takes just one second.

I'm using HeidiSQL and the strange thing is it reports:
1,578 sec. (+ 61,172 sec. network). But this makes no sense as the max() version returns roughly the same amount as data and only takes one sec.

Current indexes:

```
PRIMARY             BTREE   Yes No  id  31096905    A   YES      
code_date_unique    BTREE   Yes No  code    0       A   YES      
                                    date    0       A   YES
    code            BTREE   No  No  code 15801      A   YES      
    date            BTREE   No  No  date 1943556    A   YES
```

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `readings` (
`id` INT(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
....
`code` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_spanish_ci',
`value` FLOAT(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
....
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `code_date_unique` (`code`, `date`),
INDEX `code` (`code`),
INDEX `code_DateSaved` (`code`, `dateSaved`),
INDEX `date` (`date`),
INDEX `datesaved` (`dateSaved`),
INDEX `origen` (`origen`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_spanish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=584809517
```

Explain:

```
explain select  t.code, t.value, t.date
from readings t
inner join (
    select code, min(date) as MinDate
    from readings
    where date >= "2018-11-1"
    group by code
) tm on t.code = tm.code and t.date = tm.MinDate 

+------+---------------+--------------+---------+---------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------+---------+-----------------------------------------+
| "id" | "select_type" |   "table"    | "type"  |               "possible_keys"               |       "key"        | "key_len" |    "ref"     | "rows"  |                 "Extra"                 |
| "1"  | "PRIMARY"     | "<derived2>" | "ALL"   | \N                                          | \N                 | \N        | \N           | "15052" | ""                                      |
| "1"  | "PRIMARY"     | "t"          | "ref"   | "code_date_unique,code,code_DateSaved,date" | "date"             | "9"       | "tm.MinDate" | "16"    | "Using where"                           |
| "2"  | "DERIVED"     | "readings"   | "range" | "date"                                      | "code_date_unique" | "62"      | \N           | "10"    | "Using where; Using index for group-by" |
```

Comment: Add an index on `readings` over three columns, in order: `(date, code, value)`.

Comment: This is something I cannot understand - why you join in table `readings` the same table `readings`?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi It's a way to get the `value` associated with the lowest `date` per group. Using `min(value)` would not work for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to make your query faster by restructuring it.  But we can try adding the following index to the `readings` table:

```
(code, date, value)
CREATE INDEX your_idx ON readings (code, date, value);
```

This composite index should speed up the `GROUP BY` subquery, making it easy for MySQL to find the minimum date for each group (and also making the `WHERE` clause easier to restrict even before the `GROUP BY`).

I edited my answer to include `value` in the index, so that all the columns in your `SELECT` are covered by the index.

Comment: The index should start with `date` (otherwise it's useless in the subquery) and adding `value` to the index will allow the db engine to fulfill the entire query from the index alone.

Comment: @Tomalak Based on the documentation I have read (on the MySQL website), the column appearing in the `GROUP BY` clause should appear first, with the `date` appearing second.  You're spot on about `value`; we need to cover that column, otherwise MySQL probably won't use this index.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that too. It might depend on whether `date` is more selective than `code`, i.e. which way around it is faster to scan the second column of the index. Optimum query performance would require a second index - `(code, date)` or `(date, code)`, depending on the data composition and row count in the table, and the OP must experiment which way around it is faster. Of course more indexes decrease insert/update/deleted performance.

Comment: MySQL will probably us the index to fulfill the join, but adding the `value` column will save one round-trip to the main table. Adding a two-column clustering index to the main table can solve the issue of having "yet another index" and could even remove the need to have a separate index altogether.

Comment: So, what combination should I try first? The table has millions of rows and creating indexes takes some time. Thx

Comment: The earlier you start testing, the sooner you will be done. You won't know the difference until you actually tested all the variants anyway.

Comment: @jpp1jpp1 Also seriously consider the option of using a clustering index on the main table. If you are regularly appending rows with strictly increasing dates (as I would expect from a table called `readings`) then clustering your main table by `(date, code)` would be the most sensible choice, as `(code, date)` could cripple your insert performance.

Comment: Updated question with existing indexes

Comment: For completeness sake, also share the table definition itself, and the `EXPLAIN` result for your query.

Comment: Anyway, Tim's answer is correct. Choosing between primary key instead of stand-alone unique index, and index column order are variations that can be evaluated by trying them out, so try them out.

Comment: Added table definition and EXPLAIN (pain in the a** to format this)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183957/discussion-between-tomalak-and-jpp1jpp1).